# rspec: restarting browser on Chrome not reachable exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, selenium-chromedriver, capybara, chromium

I use rspec 3.9, capybara 3.16 and selenium-webdriver 3.141 with chrome 73 to test a large web application. I have a lot of feature specs and sooner or later chrome becomes unresponsive, I can see the window open but nothing happening. This happens in headless mode too. There's no pattern to this, it just happens at random.

```
Failure/Error: example.run

          Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
            chrome not reachable
              (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
              (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
config.after(:each, type: :feature) do |example|
   if example.exception
      # restart chrome!
   end
end
```

In combination with rspec-repeat, this will try up to 3 times. But I'm not sure how to restart the browser.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quit the session with `Capybara.current_session.quit`.  This will cause a new Chrome instance to be started on the next `visit` call.
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Session:quit

Comment: Thank you Thomas. With your help I am now restarting Chrome on example exceptions. My main issue persists though, you wouldn't happen to know how to restart chromedriver as well?